# Чтение txt файлов linux

Tags: java, linux

Добрый день есть код который должен читать файлы txt в паке, в эту папку падают файлы с названием modem.VKjUeK каждый раз имя modem остаётся прежним а тип меняется GhFJkf.
Вопрос как их читать?

Comment: Это же Java, она кроссплатформенная. Так что в Linux читать так же, как на любой другой платформе.

Answer (score 1):

Например, воспользуйтесь классом SimpleFileVisitor

```
public class FileFounder {

    private Path path;
    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getPathList() throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SFV());
        return fileList;
    }

    private class SFV extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            fileList.add(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    }
}
```